# ArrayList find custom object quickly

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashmap

I'm using `ArrayList` to store `CustomObjects`, problem is that it takes time to find an object in that list in order to remove it. (around 100K elements).

I'm forced to use `ArrayList` as I have to keep the order as is.

I was thinking of updating an `HashMap<Object, Integer>` to keep track of indexes.

Problem is when I delete an element in the list, i also have to update all indexes in my map, which is slow !

I also must be able to find elements in my list by both Index and Object.

If you can lead me to some sort of solutions :)
Thanks.

EDIT: I implemented from scratch needed LinkedList, its working like a charm, thanks for your help everyone tho :)

Comment: You can use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) - it's an implementation of the `Map` interface that maintains ordering like a `List`

Comment: WIth 100K elements, is there any reason that you couldn't keep these objects in an AVL tree? How are your key-value pairs configured? Why are you restricted to using a 1-dimensional structure like `ArrayList`?

Comment: Because I don't need Key-Value pair, and ArrayList because I want to keep order of addition of the items.

Comment: Would it be an option to mark an object as deleted by simply setting the ArrayList element to `null`? That way, the indexes of your other objects won't change.

Comment: It's an option but it's too dirty and would require lots of code modifications to check if value is null in the list.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm forced to use `ArrayList` as I have to keep the order as is.

Fortunately, you are not really forced to use `ArrayList`, because you have another option: use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which preserves order, and gives you an option to find and remove items in O(1).

With this change you would no longer be able to access items by their index, and you would need to ensure that the items you insert into the container have proper implementations for [`hashCode` and `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/335858).

> I need to find my elements with indexes too

A somewhat "dirtier" option that is available when only a small percentage of items is ever removed is keeping `null`s in the list instead of actually deleting the item. This way you could keep `HashMap<Object,Integer>` in sync with your `ArrayList`, at the expense of making additional `null` checks every time you access an item from the array list. Note that if you use this approach, the length of the list no longer signifies the number of items in your collection. Instead, you would need to use the number of items in the hash map.

Comment: If you need to store multiple times the same object in the collection, you should use `LinkedList` instead of `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: Well I tried using an LinkedList, everything went way slower, from adding to removing.

Comment: @Glidro Right, `LinkedList` wouldn't help, it would just be slower pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @Glidro `LinkedList` has an insertion/deletion avg complexity of O(n), so you really only want to use this structure when n values are low (where n is the number of values you're planning on putting into your data structure).

Comment: And I need to find my elements with indexes too, so LinkedHashSet is not possible

Comment: @Glidro You will need to figure out a way to not access objects by index, using some other key instead. Otherwise all associative containers would be out of consideration, leaving you with slow O(n) options.

Comment: @Glidro do you need to find elements by index in O(1) time? If O(n) is acceptable, you could "index into" the LinkedHashSet by iterating n times.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the null option is interesting but not viable, because the main purpose of this talk is to improve performances when removing many elements, in fact over 100K elements we might get rid of 60K at any given time, so keeping nulls is not possible.

Comment: @Glidro 100K/60K does not sound too bad, I'd actually give it a try. If you delete in batches, make a method that goes through the list+hash set for the entire batch, removing one item at a time, then walks through the remaining items, and deletes `null`s. You could also optimize removal "straight" from the array list if you collect all items to remove upfront, then  walk through the list once, copy the items that you want to keep into another list, and then replace the original list with the copy. If you do 60K items in one batch, copying may actually be faster.

Comment: Yup but the 60K are "random", I mean the process is never removing first or last 60K elements, it can remove 114 random, 2547 random, or even 90% of the whole items.

Comment: @Glidro Do you remove them all at once, or do you remove some, than add some, then remove some more, then do something else before removing some additional ones?

Comment: The process can add and remove all the time, basically it's stocking shapes to be displayed by a renderer. So many shapes can get removed/added any time, but in most cases, shapes are getting removed. Tho, if deleting, all the shapes to be deleted are deleted at once, not delayed.

Comment: @Glidro Since all the shapes that you delete are deleted at once, you should be able to make a `HashSet` of k shapes to be deleted in O(k), then walk the list once and collect all shapes that you want to keep into a new list in O(n). Finally, replace the original list with the new one. This will save you from doink O(n*k), which may be a lot slower.